# Confusing RSpec hash match diff

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm using RSpec [match](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-expectations/RSpec%2FMatchers:match) matcher to check if a hash contains expected values. When a key of the hash doesn't match, all the dynamic (`a_string_starting_with`, etc) values are shown as not matching. It's especially distracting when you try to match a bigger hash. I'm wondering if there's another way check the hash, so only the values which really do not match would show up in the diff.

Here's an example, where `a` is marked in red, although the value is correct.

```rb
it 'matches' do
  actual = {
    a: 'test test',
    b: 1,
    c: 2,
  }

  expect(actual).to match(
    a: a_string_starting_with('test'),
    b: 0,
    c: 2,
  )
end
```

[image: Match diff]

I'm wondering if there's another matcher I should use. Or if there are any custom matchers or gems for this?

Comment: Could you try this :`expect(actual).to include(a: match(/^test/), b: 1, c: 2)`

Comment: The results are the same, `a` is printed in red when `b` value is incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with this is the current differ gem used by RSpec and they are already aware of the issue, though currently no fix exists, as can be seen by these tickets:

- https://github.com/rspec/rspec-support/issues/365
- https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/issues/1120

One of the solutions in proposed for now in the ticket is similar to what Mosaaleb is suggesting.

Comment: Thanks for linking to the issues!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, this works to me:

```rb
# spec/supports/hash_diff_patcher.rb
module HashDiffPatcher
  def diff_as_object(actual, expected)
    if kind_of_hash?(actual) && kind_of_hash?(expected)
      super(actual.sort.to_h, expected.sort.to_h)
    else
      super
    end
  end

  private

  def kind_of_hash?(obj)
    # compact grape entity
    obj.instance_of?(Hash) || obj.instance_of?(Grape::Entity::Exposure::NestingExposure::OutputBuilder)
  end
end

RSpec::Support::Differ.prepend HashDiffPatcher
```